# How can I add a menu item to Gnome's window menu?

Tags: gnome

In [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/), when I right click on a window title bar, I get the window menu:

[image: gnome window menu screenshot]

How can I add a menu entry and my own custom menu callback handler to this window menu without recompiling gnome?  Is this possible?

Comment: At most you'd have to recompile the window manager.

Comment: "At least" or "at most"?  I'm in a corporate environment, I don't have root permissions, and I'd like to avoid re-compiling the WM.  Any idea if there is some sort of runtime change I can do to achieve my goal?

Comment: At most. You don't need root to use a different WM though. And of course, anything beyond this is specific to the WM.